# Malfunction via Safari

Tags: functions

I would like to ask you for your help.
The other day, I established a website of my lab （ http://hommalab.arch.kumamoto-u.ac.jp/wp/ ） using the theme "Infinity Blog" on WordPress.
It functions normally on desktops/laptops, however, there is one problem with iPhone （iPhoneXs,iOS14.6）.
Specifically, it says that "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid" every time I only click the menu bar in Safari, although I can normally see the website in the internet browser Google Chrome.
How can I edit/revise javascript on WordPress ？
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The href of the hamburger menu is incorrect

Currently its `href="javscript:(0)"`

It needs to be `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where can I edit it?
I'm sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: @Yutaro Depends on the theme. Best way is to create a child theme and override the template that is responsible for displaying that menu. This also depends on the theme if it even has a option for overriding templates with child theme. You will need to do some research about that. There is an option to change that href using `js` but that would be a dirty hack, still possible if you want

Comment: I understand your answer but could you tell me where you found that error?

Comment: Using a tool called [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) I opened your site on that device and ios, checked the site console and thats it. You can do the same on your pc, just open the console and using the `select element` tool `(ctrl+shift+c on chrome)` select the hamburger menu and check the `a` href attribute

Comment: I've just solved the problem and thanks a million!
I really appreciate your help!